# Why is switching to mobile not network-wide?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I often have to move to a small window which is practically a mobile interface, and that means I need to switch over pretty much every site I am using to the mobile interface, especially chat which is impossibly hard to switch over when needed. Can we have an option to globally switch to the mobile interface?

Comment: Right now this is done via user agent and a cookie, this would be a very large change.  Until we get something like a global network login in a central place (similar work to be done with multiple domains, etc), this one will have to wait.

Comment: That documentation applies to StackAuth itself which is an iframe only present when you're not logged in, to have it present on every authenticated request as well to make cross-domain JavaScript calls is a huge load change and not an ideal solution either.  This would need to be handled in a different way that doesn't result in a two-fold request increase for logged in users to account for when you switch between the two.

Comment: @NickCraver Could this be done server-side?